# How to call parent constructor in child classes constructor?

Tags: c++

I have searched for it and this seems to be the only way of calling a superclass constructor in C++:

```cpp
class SuperClass
{
    public:

        SuperClass(int foo)
        {
            // do something with foo
        }
};

class SubClass : public SuperClass
{
    public:

        SubClass(int foo, int bar)
        : SuperClass(foo)    // Call the superclass constructor in the subclass' initialization list.
        {
            // do something with bar
        }
};
```

But I'd like to know, how can I call the superclass constructor in the constructor body instead of initialization list?

I have to process inputs of my child's constructor and pass complex processed parameters to superclass constructor, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A base class constructor must be run to initialize the base before you can enter the body of the derived class constructor. The Member Initializer List is the only way to initialize the base class. If you have complex requirements for the parameters, use helper functions to compute the parameters.

Example:

```cpp
class SuperClass
{
    public:

        SuperClass(int foo)
        {
            // do something with foo
        }
};

class SubClass : public SuperClass
{
    private:
        static int basehelper(int foo)
        {
            // do complicated things to foo
            return result_of_complicated_things;
        }
    public:

        SubClass(int foo, int bar)
        : SuperClass(basehelper(foo))    // Call the superclass constructor in the subclass' initialization list.
        {
            // do something with bar
        }
};
```

If the base class parameters require knowledge known only as the derived class is constructed, you must either

- Duplicate the effort,
- Find a way to memoize the results of the helper (perhaps insert a layer of abstraction) and apply the results later in construction,
- Modify the base class to have a simpler constructor and support Two-Phase Initialization, or
- Do something entirely different. Perhaps [Composition Over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) is good advice for your use case.

Comment: `basehelper` should probably be static (or a non-member function) since you're calling it before the object is fully constructed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The parent portion of your class must be initialized before your child can start. So you have to do it at the front of your initializer list.

However, you could have Superclass::initialize() that does what you need to do, and your Superclass constructor can call it.

Comment: Do you mean "*your **SubClass** constructor can call it*" instead?

Comment: Well, I guess I meant both can call it.

Comment: That wouldn't make much sense, as that would lead to double-initialization

Comment: @RemyLebeau That depends on how heavy your default constructor is. By the time you're actually inside your constructor, the superclass will have been constructed. There's no getting around that part. You can choose which constructor you want, and you can call methods to do further initialization.